# How do I use loop in the following problem?

Tags: sas

I want to loop through some variables and create nine new variables which are equal to 1 if the first three variables are "433" or "434". I am using the following code but its showing 1 for everything, can someone help

```
data icd_dim;
set asg3;
array icd (9) $ ICD9_DGNS_CD_1-ICD9_DGNS_CD_9;
array flag_icd (9) flag_icd_1-flag_icd_9;
do i = 1 to 9;
if icd(i)=substr(icd(i),1,3)="433" OR "434" then flag_icd(i)=1; end;
run;
```

Comment: What do you think `("433" or "434")` evaluates to?  Is that TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: Do you mean "first three characters" instead of "first the variables"  ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `IN` operator to compare one value to a list of value.  Your current code is testing if `"433"` is True or False.  Since it is non-blank it is treated as True.

You want:

```
if substr(icd(i),1,3) in ("433" "434") then flag_icd(i)=1;
```

Or to eliminate the missing values just assign the result of the test to the variable and get either 1 (true) or 0 (false).

```
flag_icd(i) =  substr(icd(i),1,3) in ("433" "434") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `in:` operator is a prefix comparison operator for character values.  You also might want a flag variable name that is more descriptive of the diagnosis.

```
occlusion_flag(i) = icd(i) in: ('433', '434');
```